# Replacing the page url with another one with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, window, document

I know there is plenty on the subject but not what exactly i want...

I've tried `window.location.replace("http://gmail.com")`but it replaces the content only in a specific `<div>` in the page instead of the whole page..

In the w3schools tutorials of `location.replace` for example

`http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_replace`

It allows you to load the new URL in the box on the right of the page.

In my case, i want a javascript that will replace the whole page, and not only in the small box on the right.

I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean, "the right box of the page"?  *What* page?

Comment: This page : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_replace

Comment: It's an iframe. When you do it normally, the whole page will be replaced.

Comment: I mean it replaces it just in a specific <div> instead of changing the whole page URL.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to replace the page even if it is in a frame. It is related to personalization of Moodle and i can not play in the HTML file

Comment: @user3442206 I just typed in an answer, and it works fine in that w3schools test page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've got code in an `<iframe>`. If so, you can reload the whole browser window/tab with

```
window.top.location.replace("http://gmail.com");
```